# HashDict and OTP GenServer context within Elixir

Tags: dictionary, elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

I am having trouble using the `HashDict` function within OTP. I would like to use one `GenServer` process to `put` and a different one to `fetch`. When I try and implement this, I can put and fetch items from the `HashDict` when calling from the same GenServer; it works perfectly (`MyServerA` in the example below). But when I use one `GenServer` to `put` and a different one to `fetch`, the fetch implementation does not work. Why is this? Presumably it's because I need to pass the `HashDict` data structure around between the three different processes?

Code example below:

I use a simple call to send some state to `MyServerB`:

```py
    MyServerA.add_update(state)
```

For `MyServerB` I have implemented the `HashDict` as follows:

```py
defmodule MyServerB do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,[], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init([]) do
    #Initialise HashDict to store state
    d = HashDict.new
    {:ok, d}
  end

  #Client API
  def add_update(update) do
    GenServer.cast __MODULE__, {:add, update}
  end

  def get_state(window) do
    GenServer.call __MODULE__, {:get, key}
  end

  # Server APIs 
  def handle_cast({:add, update}, dict) do
    %{key: key} = update
    dict = HashDict.put(dict, key, some_Value)
  {:noreply, dict}
  end

  def handle_call({:get, some_key}, _from, dict) do
    value = HashDict.fetch!(dict, some_key)
    {:reply, value, dict}
  end
end
```

So if from another process I use `MyServerB.get_state(dict,some_key)`, I don't seem to be able to return the contents of the `HashDict`...

UPDATE:

So if I use ETS I have something like this:

```py
def init do
   ets = :ets.new(:my_table,[:ordered_set, :named_table])
   {:ok, ets}
end

def handle_cast({:add, update}, state) do
   update = :ets.insert(:my_table, {key, value})
   {:noreply, ups}
end 

def handle_call({:get, some_key}, _from, state) do
   sum = :ets.foldl(fn({{key},{value}}, acc) 
        when key == some_Key -> value + acc 
                      (_, acc) ->
                         acc 
                       end, 0, :my_table) 
   {:reply, sum, state}
end
```

So again, the `cast` works - when I check with `observer` I can see the its filling up with my key value pairs. However, when I try my `call` it returns nothing again. So I'm wondering if I'm handling the state incorrectly?? Any help, gratefully received??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with this statement:

> I would like to use one GenServer process to put and a different one to fetch.

In Elixir processes cannot share state. So you cannot have one process with data, and another process reading it directly. You could for example, store the HashDict in one process and then have the other process send a message to the first asking for data. That would make it appear as you describe, however behind the scenes it would still have all transactions go through the first process. There are techniques for doing this in a distributed/concurrent fashion so that multiple cores are utilize but that may be more work than you're looking to do at the moment.

Take a look at ETS, which will allow you to create a public table and access the data from multiple processes.

Comment: thanks for this. So I tried your suggestion, and I have (to my naive understanding) a similar problem. I have edited the original question...

Answer (score 1):

ETS is the way to go. Share a HashDict as state between GenServers is not possible.

I really don't know how you are testing your code, but ETS by default has read and write concurrency to false. For example, if you have no problem with reading or writing concurrently then you can change your init function to:

```
def init do
  ets = :ets.new :my_table, [:ordered_set, :named_table,
                             read_concurrency: true,
                             write_concurrency: true]
  {:ok, ets}
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has made a difference :-) However, I now get the following error: ` an exception was raised: ** (ArgumentError) argument error:ets.safe_fixtable(true, true)` - I suspect this is because I am doing an `insert` and `foldl` concurrently? From looking at the erlang documentation it seems there is a setting to fix the ETS table, but I'm not sure how to do this or whether this is intact the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Are you using `Enum.foldl/3`? ETS has its own `foldl` function. From the documentation:

Comment: "If Function inserts objects into the table, or **another process inserts objects into the table, those objects may (depending on key ordering) be included in the traversal.**" I believe if you use that function you shouldn't have any problem when inserting. If you really want to use `List.foldl/3` or delete records concurrently you should look at this post [http://stackoverflow.com/a/20338795/4776680]. It explains how to use `safe_fixtable`.

Comment: I am using `:ets.foldl` - I've got it working now, thanks for your help!